# How to translate “prequel”?

Tags: translation

How to translate [“prequel”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prequel) to Esperanto? I can't find it in Wikipedia, Reta Vortaro and the English-Esperanto dictionary of John C. Wells. A prequel is a work (for example a book or a movie) that is set chronologically before its predecessor. It isn't a direct antonym to the word “sequel”.

Kiel oni traduku la anglan [“prequel”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prequel) al Esperanto? Mi ne povas trovi ĝin en Vikipedio, Reta Vortaro kaj la angla-esperanta vortaro de John C. Wells. Temas pri verko (ekzemple libro aŭ filmo), kiu kronologie okazas antaŭ la antaŭe eldonita verko. Ĝi ne estas rekta antonimo de la angla vorto “sequel”.

Comment: Same ŝajne mankas termino por _sequel_. Estus konsilinde trovi strukturon, kiu permesas esprimi ambaŭ, ekz. _antaŭ-X-o_ - _post-X-o_.

Answer (score 4):

Ne ofte, sed tamen atesteble en la Tekstaro, estas uzata la esprimo *antaŭhistorio* por nomi ion, kio okazis antaŭ iu ĉefa historia okazaĵo (Krome, sed ŝajne nur en la Reta Vortaro, tiu esprimo aperas kiel sinonimo al *prahistorio*, kio estas nekonsilinda).
Oni povus facile transpreni ĝin al la sfero de filmo, kaj nomi tian filmon depende de la kunteksto *(filma) antaŭhistorio* aŭ *antaŭhistoria filmo*.

Simile la anglan *sequel* oni povus traduki per *(filma) posthistorio" aŭ "posthistoria filmo".

Answer (score 1):

Paŭzita termino el aliaj lingvoj:

- *praepizodo* = prequel

Comment: Jes, temas pri epizodo, do _antaŭ-_ aŭ _postepizodo_.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas ekzakte. Kaj por poste verkita epizodo kiu eksplikus la origino tempe antaŭ la unua publikigita epizodo oni povus diri praepizodo.

Answer (score 1):

*antaŭ-* prefikse povus utili, ĉu por *antaŭserio*, ĉu por aferoj kiel *antaŭrakonto*.

Oni do havus (oni povas anstataŭigi *serio* per *rakonto*):

antaŭserio -> serio (ĉefa) -> postserio, disserio (ekzemple por *spinoff*).

Answer (score 0):

The correct word is *antaŭepizodo*.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple : if you say sekvaĵo to mean "sequel", malsekvaĵo is the word for "prequel".

Answer (score 0):

Epizodo is quite a difficult word for non-romance language speakers, to English speakers episode sounds pedantic.  Seriero (element of a series or serial) is better international-wise, as all TV viewers of the world have heard the word series.  Ersekvo, or sekva seriero is a sequel.  Ermalsekvo or malsekva seriero is a prequel.